# Java generics How to accept any derived type in generic parameter

Tags: java, generics

In The below 2 lines of code

```
HashMap<Integer, ?extends Collection<String>> map=
                                           new HashMap<Integer, TreeSet<String>>();

map.put(1,new TreeSet<String>());
```

Line 2 :The method put(Integer, capture#1-of ? extends Collection) in the type HashMap> is not applicable for the arguments (int, TreeSet)

Line 1: this has no error.

Why is the same generic type (TreeSet< String >) allowed in Line 1 but not allowed in Line 2?

Edit :
With super instead of extends ,why is the following is NOT allowed.

```
HashMap<Integer, ?super Collection<String>> map=new HashMap(<Integer, TreeSet<String>>());
```

but

```
HashMap<Integer, ?super Collection<String>> map=new HashMap();
map.put(1,new TreeSet<String>());
```

is allowed

Answer (score 3):

The reason you get a compiler error is the same reason you cannot add a `Dog` to a `List<? extends Animal>` -- you cannot call a method with a generic parameter when the type of the reference variable has an upper bound wildcard.  The `map` variable's value type parameter could refer to *any* type that matches `? extends Collection<String>`, perhaps as `HashMap<Integer, LinkedList<String>>`.  You could legally insert this line before the call to `put`:

```
map = new HashMap<Integer, LinkedList<String>>();
```

The compiler doesn't know the exact type that's really in the map, so it must, at compile time, prevent you from `put`ting a `TreeSet<String>` in as a value to a map whose value could be something like `LinkedList<String>`.

To `put` a value in `map` (besides `null`), you must remove the wildcard.

```
HashMap<Integer, TreeSet<String>> map =
         new HashMap<Integer, TreeSet<String>>();
```

As JB Nizet has commented, you still can put a value of any `Collection` such as `TreeSet` if you remove the wildcard but keep `Collection`.

```
HashMap<Integer, Collection<String>> map =
         new HashMap<Integer, Collection<String>>();
```

(Also, the diamond operator can simplify the declarations here.)

#### In response to the changes added to the question:

Here, you've used a lower bound.

```
HashMap<Integer, ? super Collection<String>> map = new HashMap<Integer, TreeSet<String>>());
```

The type parameter may be `Collection<String>` or any supertype, such as `Object`.  This disallows subtypes such as `TreeSet<String>`.  Java's generics are invariant.  The only reason any variation from `Collection<String>` is allowed is because of the wildcard.

```
HashMap<Integer, ? super Collection<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(1, new TreeSet<String>());
```

This is allowed because any supertype of `Collection<String>` will match any subtype as an argument.  After all, a `TreeSet<String>` is an `Object`.  A `TreeSet<String>` can be `put` as a value to `map`, whether it's a `HashMap<Integer, Object>` or a `HashMap<Integer, Collection<String>>`, or any type in between.  The compiler can prove type safety, so it allows the call.

Comment: Or, if the map must accept any kind of collection of strings, `Map<Integer, Collection<String>> map = new HashMap<Integer, Collection<String>>();`, which can be reduced to `Map<Integer, Collection<String>> map = new HashMap<>();`

Comment: @JBNizet Even better; I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: what if he casts the TreeSet<String> to Collection<String> can he put in the map

Comment: A `Map` is *not* a `Collection`, so `new HashMap...whatever...` does not match `? extends Collection<String>`.

Comment: @achabahe No.  It has nothing to do with the type of what's being passed as the value in the call to `put` and everything to do with the wildcard.

Comment: @Rogério I didn't say that a `Map` is a `Collection`.  I didn't demonstrate putting a `Map` into `map` as a value.

Comment: Ah, ok, I misread the part saying "The map variable's value type parameter could refer to any type that matches ? extends Collection<String>, perhaps as...".

Comment: @Rogério Assuming it was you who downvoted, would you like to reconsider your vote?

Comment: Too late, SO doesn't allow me to undo the vote anymore, "unless this answer is edited" (from the SO error message). I didn't remember the answer to the question myself one hour ago, now I see it again: the key is to understand that a type declaration like `Map<Integer, ? extends Collection<String>>` can accept values (maps here) of *incompatible (concrete) types between themselves*, such as `HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>>` and `HashMap<Integer, TreeSet<String>>`. So, maybe the answer could be edited to clarify this. -- ok, downvote rolled back now

Answer (score 1):

The declaration of the map tells the compiler that a value inside in the map is some collection of strings. At runtime, it could be a `TreeSet` but it could also be some other collection type. Hence the compiler cannot allow putting a `TreeSet` since it may actually contain `ArrayList` values.

More generally, whenever you use a bound type argument using the `?` wildcard, you are practically only allowed to read from the map (e.g. iterate over its elements). In other words, you can always do:

```
for(Iterator<? extends Collection<String>> iterator = map.values().iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    Collection<String> collection = iterator.next();
    ... 
}
```

In your case, however, since you're adding a `TreeSet` it means that most likely you know that the map *will* contain `TreeSet` values, so you don't need to use a wildcard:

```
HashMap<Integer, TreeSet<String>> map = new HashMap<>(); // In Java 7+, you can use the diamond operator when creating the HashMap
```

Answer (score 0):

Compiler says:

> no suitable method found for put(int,TreeSet)
>           map.put(1, new TreeSet());
>       method HashMap.put(Integer,CAP#1) is not applicable
>         (actual argument TreeSet cannot be converted to CAP#1 by method invocation conversion)
>       method AbstractMap.put(Integer,CAP#1) is not applicable
>         (actual argument TreeSet cannot be converted to CAP#1 by method invocation conversion)   where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
>       CAP#1 extends Collection from capture of ? extends Collection

I think it's because of type ambiguity for compiler and as [AR.3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35899702/3208640) sayed:

> The declaration of the map tells the compiler that a value inside in
>   the map is some collection of strings. At runtime, it could be a
>   TreeSet but it could also be some other collection type.

If the type be certain for the compiler the code will compiles and runs without any problem, for instance you can write your code as below which compiles and runs successfully:

```
public <T extends Collection<String>> void someVoid(){
        //...
        //...
        HashMap<Integer, T > map
                = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(1,(T) (new TreeSet<String>()));
        //...
        //...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading the other answers and thinking some more about the original question (which was really about having the "`? extends`" part versus not having it), I came up with the following example, which should be easier to understand.

Suppose we have this method:

```
void doSomething(Collection<? extends Number> numbers) { ... }
```

And the following usages elsewhere:

```
Collection<Integer> integers = asList(1, 2, 3);
Collection<Long> longs = asList(1L, 2L, 3L);
doSomething(integers);
doSomething(longs);
```

All of the above compiles fine. Now, let's ask, what can the `doSomething` method do with the collection it receives? Can it *add* some number to it? The answer is *no*, it can't. And that's because it would be unsafe; for example, if it added an `Integer` (which is a `Number`), then the `doSomething(longs)` call would fail. So, to prevent such possibilities the compiler disallows any attempt to add any `Number` at all to a `Collection<? extends Number>`.

Similarly, what if the method was declared as:

```
void doSomething(Collection<Number> numbers) { ... }
```

In this case, the method *can* add any number to the collection, but then calls like `doSomething(integers)` become compiler errors, since a collection of `Integer` can *only* accept integers. So, again, the compiler prevents the possiblity for `ClassCastException`s later, ensuring the code is type safe.