# How to use Class Objects with Inheritance

Tags: java, class, object, inheritance

I have a parent class, `Parent`, with two child classes, `A` and `B`. A have a class, `Wrapper`, that contains an interface, `Function`, which allows the programmer to specify a particular method for each wrapper.

`Wrapper` contains the variables, `Class<Parent> inputClass` and `Class<Parent> outputClass`, which specify the input and output type. `Wrapper` is supposed to map an A to an A or B, or a B to an A or B.

My problem arises when I try to call the wrapper constructor, `Wrapper(Class<Parent> input, Class<Parent> output, Function func)`. Eclipse gives me an error for trying to put an `A.class` or `B.class` in for either `input` or `output`. Given that A and B are child classes of Parent, I thought they would be able to pass into the constructor. How can I implement this?

```
public class Parent {
    protected int value;
    public void setValue(int x){ value = x; }
    public int getValue(){ return value; }
}


public class A extends Parent{
    public A(){ setValue(1); }
    public A(B b){ setValue( b.getValue()); }
}

public class B extends Parent{
    public B(){ setValue(2); }
    public B(A a){ setValue(a.getValue()); }
}


public class Wrapper{
    protected Class<? extends Parent> inputClass;
    protected Class<? extends Parent> outputClass;
    protected interface Function{
        public Parent of(Parent input);
    }
    protected Function function;
    public Wrapper(Class<? extends Parent> in, Class<? extends Parent> out, Function func) {
        inputClass = in;
        outputClass = out;
        function = func;
    }

    public Parent of(Parent input){
        try{
            Parent output = function.of( inputClass.getConstructor( input.getClass() ).newInstance(input) );
            return outputClass.getConstructor( output.getClass() ).newInstance( output );
        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ///Error occurs here. Can't take A.class in for Parent.class
        Wrapper wrapper = new Wrapper(A.class,B.class, new Function(){
            @Override
            public Parent of(Parent p) {
                return null;
            }
        });     
    }
}
```

Comment: I think `Class<Parent> in` should be more like `Class<? super Parent> in`, but I've not tried, so you might need to fudge it a bit more (you'd have to apply it to both parameters)

Comment: I think you need `<? extends Parent>` in your `Wrapper` constructor so that sub-classes are permitted. Otherwise you are restricting `in` and `out` to `Parent` only.

Comment: Possible duplicate [Java generics How to accept any derived type in generic parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35899493/java-generics-how-to-accept-any-derived-type-in-generic-parameter)

Comment: @dave I made those changes but it's still giving me the same error. I had actually tried that before posting.

Comment: @user2303321 Can you double-check? I copied your latest code into IntelliJ and it compiled without error (with Java 8) for me.

Comment: @dave I'm using Java 7, so maybe that's the problem.

Comment: @dave I'm getting the same error for Parent.class instead of A.class or B.class, so I think the error is something else.

Comment: You really want `Wrapper` to be a generic, with type parameters for the input class and the output class.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem That was my original structure, but I kept running into problems down the road, due to not being able to initialize generics.

Answer (score 1):

The problem wasn't from `A.class` or `B.class`, but from the interface `Function` being nested within the `Wrapper` class. I needed to write `new Wrapper.Function`in the constructor in main.